# Swift OSX programmatically create checkbox buttons

Tags: macos, checkbox, swift3, nsbutton

I would like to programmatically add buttons to a NSScrollView "folderScrollView". In the full application it will have anywhere from 3-8 folders. I looked up the documentation for swift 3 but it says that `"init(checkboxWithTitle: String, target: Any?, action: Selector?)"` is only available with 10.12, I need to use it on 10.10 computers.

[image]

Comment: NSButton has a state property which you can set to NSOnState.

Comment: I first need to programmatically to create it.

Comment: var newBut = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 30, height: 30)). then just set the appropriate buttonType.

Comment: This works....checkboxWithTitle.setButtonType(NSSwitchButton). How do I get the checkbox to be on the right?

Comment: Set the button's frame.

Comment: rocky not sure I follow. Can you provide an example?

Comment: button.frame = NSMakeRect(200, 100, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)